# How can I open/convert a .wpostx file?

Tags: windows-live-writer

Someone just sent me a .wpostx file and told me it was a photo. I found a reference to it being a Windows Live Writer format but I can't figure out how to open it there. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename the file
"filename".wpost   instead of "filename".wpostx

this has kind of worked for me